# find phrase in column and copy rows of data to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to find an answer to this everywhere but have not come across a simple solution.

I have a a sheet of data with columns:

ID, Department, DeptCode, Sales, Product, StartDate, EndDate

I did try start the foundation with a macro but it does not seem to work:

```
Sheets("TEST").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AO$10").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
    "=SAL"
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I am trying to search the column 'department' to find the phrase "Sal" which could be part of a longer string and then copy that row to a different sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Replace `"=SAL"` by  `"*SAL*"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a header row (not sure what your data set looks like), then you could use the below to copy everything below the header:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Copy
```

Changing `"=SAL"` to `"=*SAL*"` will alter the filter to include anything containing "SAL".